# How do I get column data from tableview?

Tags: xcode, macos, tableview

I have the following code in a macOS app using Xcode 11 for a right click on a tableView row:

```
// right click action
      override func rightMouseDown(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
        let point = tableView.convert(theEvent.locationInWindow, from: nil)
        let row = tableView.row(at: point)
        
            // Add popup menu
        print("right click")
        print(row)
      }
```

I would like to know if I can get the column data at this point. If so, how is this done? I looked at the tableView object using the debugger but I don't see the column data?

Comment: There is also `column(at:` but you should get the data from the model, the data source array.

Comment: Thanks I used the model as you suggested. Thanks